# How do i calculate the total cost of items the user selects from 5 comboboxs

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have done 600 lines of code and made five comboboxes I am able to display the price for each item but cannot display the total of the items selected here is the code for one of the comboboxes that I have done.

```
    lights.setConverter(new StringConverter<Light>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Light object) {
            return object.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Light fromString(String string) {
            return null;
        }
    });



    lights.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList
           (new Light ("Incandescent", 5.23),
            new Light ("Halogen", 5.75),
            new Light ("fluorescent",7.29),
            new Light ("Compact fluorescent bulbs",4.83),
            new Light ("LED",4.83)));


    lights.setPromptText("Please select a light");
    lights.setPrefWidth(100);


         lights.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
         String selectionText = "The price for the " + newVal.getName() + " light is : $" + newVal.getPrice();
       lightNamePrice.setText(selectionText);
    });

 private class Light {
    private String name;
    private Double price;

    private Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private Light(String name, Double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;

    }

}
```

Am i doing this right?
What do i have to do to find the total cost of the items the user selects with 4 other comboboxes like this one?

Comment: I know on listView it is listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems(), try that on the combo box and it might work.

Comment: 600 lines of code for a few combo boxes seems excessive. You might want to think about ways to reduce that. (If code is repetitive, factor it into other classes or methods as appropriate.)

Comment: @James_D What I have done is each combo box has its own private class like the lights combo box has private class Light and the next combo box switches has private class switch and so on. is there a way I can use one private class all the 5 combo boxes. ?

Comment: That sounds like a different question; you should ask a new question for that and post enough code to show what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Use a binding:

```
DoubleBinding total = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    double total = 0 ;
    if (lights.getValue() != null) total += lights.getValue().getPrice();
    // similarly for other combo boxes...
    return total ;
}, lights.valueProperty(), otherComboBox.valueProperty() /* etc for other combos*/);
```

and then you can do things like

```
totalPriceLabel.textProperty().bind(total.asString());
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything for this?

Comment: Just the obvious two classes referenced in the code: `javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding` and `javafx.beans.binding.Bindings`.